# ActionPerformed dentro de MVC

Tags: java, mvc, java-swing

Tengo una duda acerca de un proyecto que estoy realizando, la cual es la siguiente: Me exigen un proyecto con formato MVC, ya tengo la vista y el modelo, necesito realizar el ActionPerformed de cada boton de mi proyecto los cuales son aproximadamente 11 botones de tipo JButton, quisiera saber como lo puedo realizar en el proyecto, tan solo es presionar el boton y llamar al metodo de leer el archivo de cada uno de los grupos para asi mostrar la informacion del mismo, dejo el codigo enlazado:

MODELO

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package modelo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Diablo
 */
public class rusiaModelo extends JFrame{

    public void LeerGrupoA() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        String grupoA;
        FileReader gA= new FileReader("grupoA.txt");
        BufferedReader a=new BufferedReader(gA);
        while((grupoA=a.readLine())!=null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,grupoA);
        }
       a.close();

    }
    public void LeerGrupoB() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        String grupoB;
        FileReader gB= new FileReader("grupoB.txt");
        BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(gB);
        while((grupoB=b.readLine())!=null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,grupoB);
        }
       b.close();
    }
    public void LeerGrupoC() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        String grupoC;
        FileReader gC= new FileReader("grupoC.txt");
        BufferedReader c=new BufferedReader(gC);
        while((grupoC=c.readLine())!=null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,grupoC);
        }
       c.close();
    }
    public void LeerGrupoD() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        String grupoD;
        FileReader gD= new FileReader("grupoD.txt");
        BufferedReader d=new BufferedReader(gD);
        while((grupoD=d.readLine())!=null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,grupoD);
        }
       d.close();
    }
    public void LeerGrupoE() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        String grupoE;
        FileReader gE= new FileReader("grupoE.txt");
        BufferedReader e=new BufferedReader(gE);
        while((grupoE=e.readLine())!=null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,grupoE);
        }
       e.close();
    }
    public void LeerGrupoF() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        String grupoF;
        FileReader gF= new FileReader("grupoF.txt");
        BufferedReader f=new BufferedReader(gF);
        while((grupoF=f.readLine())!=null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,grupoF);
        }
       f.close();
    }
    public void LeerGrupoG() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        String grupoG;
        FileReader gG= new FileReader("grupoG.txt");
        BufferedReader g=new BufferedReader(gG);
        while((grupoG=g.readLine())!=null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,grupoG);
        }
       g.close();
    }
    public void LeerGrupoH() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        String grupoH;
        FileReader gH= new FileReader("grupoH.txt");
        BufferedReader h=new BufferedReader(gH);
        while((grupoH=h.readLine())!=null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,grupoH);
        }
       h.close();
    }
}
```

CONTROLADOR

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controlador;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashSet;
import modelo.rusiaModelo;
import vista.Vista;

public class Controlador implements ActionListener {

    private Vista view;
    private rusiaModelo model;

    public Controlador(Vista view, rusiaModelo model){
        this.view= view;
        this.model=model;
        this.view.botonGrupoA.addActionListener(this);
        this.view.botonGrupoB.addActionListener(this);
        this.view.botonGrupoC.addActionListener(this);
        this.view.botonGrupoD.addActionListener(this);
        this.view.botonGrupoE.addActionListener(this);
        this.view.botonGrupoF.addActionListener(this);
        this.view.botonGrupoG.addActionListener(this);
        this.view.botonGrupoH.addActionListener(this);

    }
    public void iniciar()
    {
        view.setTitle("Mundial Rusia");
        view.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){



    }

}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar a solucionar mi problema...

PDTA: Intente con un:

```
If(botonGrupoA.isSelected){
model.LeerA();
}
```

Pero no funciono... Muchas gracias por la respuesta de Antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Doy el tema por finalizado, ya pude solucionar el error que tenia en la lectura de archivos y en el ActionPerformed de cada boton creado, muchas gracias a las personas que respondieron.

Answer (score -1):

En teoría el método getSource() de un evento (ActionEvent) te da donde se originó el evento. Si usas JButton entonces te debe dar el objeto que activó el evento. Viendo como agregas los escuchadores en el la clase Controlador, esto debe funcionar:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    Object origen = e.getSource();
    try {
       if (origen == this.view.botonGrupoA) { leeGrupoA(); }
       else if (origen == this.view.botonGrupoB) { leeGrupoB(); }
       //etcetera
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
       ///lo que quieras hacer con tu excepción
    }
}
```

Estoy agregando el try-catch porque veo que tus métodos tiran excepciones.

Comment: Ya lo habia resulto de la misma manera que tu me lo acabas de decir, pero con model.LeerTexto("grupoA.txt), pero aun asi me inicia y no me saca ningun error, pero tampoco leer el archivo de texto el cual contiene el grupoA.

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que al momento de presionar el boton de grupo A muestre los datos que hay dentro de un archivo de txt previamente leido con la clase rusiaModelo.

Comment: Con lo que acabas de comentar, no entiendo entonces cual es tu problema actual. Saludos

Comment: El problema que publique ya lo solucione ya que cree el actionperformed de cada uno de los botones, pero ahora hago la lectura del archivo de cada boton pero no muestra los datos del archivos al momento de clickear en el boton.